# using Onclick - Change text separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a on-click function to change text...In two span tags. But the prob is one i click the 2nd span. . the first span text is getting changed. . when I click the span then the text in it only should change. . .In future I will be adding more span. . so it should work for that also. . need to change the code so that it will work for all span separately.

HTML

```
<h2 class = "trigger">2012-2013
<span id="element1" onClick="javascript:changeText(1);">[+]</span></h2>
 <div class = "toggle">
 <h4>Annual Report (2012-2013)</h4>

<h2 class = "trigger">2013-2014
<span id="element2" onClick="javascript:changeText(3);">[+]</span></h2>
 <div class = "toggle">
 <h4>Annual Report (2013-2014)</h4>
```

JS

```
function changeText(idElement) {
var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2) {
    if (element.innerHTML === '[+]') element.innerHTML = '[-]';
    else {
        element.innerHTML = '[+]';
    }
}
}

function changeText(idElement) {
var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
if (idElement === 3 || idElement === 2) {
    if (element.innerHTML === '[+]') element.innerHTML = '[-]';
    else {
        element.innerHTML = '[+]';
    }
}
}
```

Trigger function:

```
$('.trigger').next('.toggle').hide();
$('.trigger').click(function() {
var el = $(this).next('.toggle');
var doit = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.toggle').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
});
```

FIDDLE

[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sH9B6/4/)

Comment: Text is changed to what..? In future if you're adding span, how does the code know to what text it should be changed, unless you're using some database or so...? you're question is unclear...

Comment: @T J: All the span onclick function has the same text change if  [+] on clicking this it should change to [-] then clicking again it will change back to [+]. If there is anyway to make the code compact

Comment: @T J: I have a trigger function in it, which i didn't post please see

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sH9B6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the spans state between `+` and `-` then you can make use of `this` to make it work for all of them, you don't actually even need an id..

```
<span onClick="changeText(this);">[+]</span>


function changeText(element) {
if (element.innerHTML === '[+]')
 element.innerHTML = '[-]';
else
    element.innerHTML = '[+]';
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/sH9B6/)

**Updated**

as per the update,  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/sH9B6/7/) with slide

Comment: @Zain removing an accepted answer for additional functionality is really discouraging...if you want to modify the question, properly update the question... (please remove the comments and add the desired functionality in question..) otherwise someone referring this quesiion will get confused.. if you want some other additional functionality in a particulor answer - just comment below the answer, http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/sH9B6/5/

Comment: Its working now. But Once I click the 2nd span the first span should close. . in the sense only one span should be open at a time. .

Comment: @T J: any solutions buddy. . .

Comment: @T J: Looks like its malfunctioning

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/sH9B6/7/ i don't know why you edited the `answer` and added an additional requirement in it..!, but like i said, if you want to mention something about the question, please update it in the **question** (and delete the unnecessory comments here and the ones below the question regarging trigger update those in the **question** plesase..)

Answer (score 4):

because both have the same id `element1`

`getElementById()` method accesses the first element with the specified id.

use
**html**

```
<span id="element1" onClick="javascript:changeText(this.id);">[+]</span>
```

**script**

```
function changeText(eleId) {
 var element = document.getElementById(eleId);
   if (element.innerHTML === '[+]') {
        element.innerHTML = '[-]';
    }
    else {
        element.innerHTML = '[+]';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sH9B6/3/

Comment: I changed it. . But What I need a universal code which will be applicable for each span seperately

Comment: If I have 30 or 40 span with this click function.  ..The code will become so big

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two different functions with same same. Combine the functionality into a single function. In addition "id" of elements must be unique. Please change that too.

```
function changeText(idElement) {
 var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
 if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2 || idElement === 3) {
    if (element.innerHTML === '[+]') {
        element.innerHTML = '[-]';
    }
    else {
        element.innerHTML = '[+]';
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u may update like this:

**html**

```
<span onclick="changeText(this);">[+]</span>
```

**js**

```
function changeText(el) {
  var p = "[+]", m = "[-]", txt = p;
  if (p === el.innerHTML) {
    txt = m;
  }
  el.innerHTML = txt;
}
```